# Checking for a pure string using regexp_like

Tags: regex, oracle11g

I need to check a "substring of the first 6 characters" of an input string for a pure string.

```
declare
p_str varchar2(30) := 'ABCD1240';
l_result varchar2(20);

begin
if REGEXP_LIKE(substr(p_str,1,6), '[[:alpha:]]') then
        dbms_output.put_line('It is a pure string');
else
        dbms_output.put_line('It is an alphanumeric');
end if; 
end;
/
```

I can see that the first 6 characters of the string ABCD1290 is alphanumeric as it contains 12.
But, the output that is printed says otherwise.

Am I doing something wrong with the "alpha" in regexp_like ? 
I thought alpha was supposed to be pure characters and not numbers.
Here, ABCD1290 should give me: alphanumeric as output.
ABCDXY90 should be : pure string

Comment: Try `^[[:alpha:]]{6}`

Comment: I don't know regexps on Oracle, but I guess you forgot cardinality: `^[[:alpha:]]+$`.

Comment: Don't you want `substr` to start at character 0 ?

Comment: Or could skip substr and just use `if REGEXP_LIKE( p_str, '^[[:alpha:]]{6}' ) then`

Comment: yup. REGEXP_LIKE( p_str, '^[[:alpha:]]{6}' ) worked as well as REGEXP_LIKE( substr(p_str,1,6), '^[[:alpha:]]+$' ). The mistake I did was to substr the first 6 characters and not use "+$" at the end. thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare
  l_res varchar2(100);
begin
  for i in (select 'abcdef123' val from dual union 
            select '123abc123' from dual union
            select '123456abc' from dual)
  loop
    if REGEXP_LIKE(i.val, '^\D{6}')
    then
      l_res := 'alpha';
    else
      l_res := 'numeric';
    end if;
    dbms_output.put_line(i.val || ' is ' || l_res);
  end loop;
end;

123456abc is numeric
123abc123 is numeric
abcdef123 is alpha
```

Comment: Thanks. What does the \D stand for ?

Comment: Non-digits, {6} means I need exactly 6 Non-digits. ^ means I need exactly 6 Non-digits in the start of a string

Comment: It sucks. but, it turns out we cannot use regexp_like to check for the string as our application tool does not support it. Is there a way to do this only using the basic inbuilt oracle functions such as substr and instr ?

Comment: Tell me more, why can't you use REGEXP? Oracle provide this functionality out-of-box for all the editions. Do you want to connect MSSQL and ORACLE? or what?

Comment: @Casey It seems to me that you need to start a new question, because this question has been answered already and new requirements don't fit the title of the question.

Comment: yes..i Will..However, I cannot upvote your answer(although yours is correct too) as folks have asnwered my question before under comments before you responded and they work.

Comment: Also, non-digits doesn't mean only alphabets. It can include other characters also.